# Interrupt long task with small other task

Tags: microsoft-project

Using Project Pro 2016: I have got a task that lasts for 4 weeks. However I know that the Person will have to do a couple of days work next week Tuesday and Wednesday.

What's the best way to model this in Project? Can I still have only 1 long Task that is being automatically paused next week Tuesday and Wednesday because of my other task?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the short duration tasks to a higher priority.  Level the resource and make sure the option to split tasks and level by priority is selected.